# Merging multiple results rows after STRING_SPLIT on left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume an application where a user can select an items from a table `fruits` to add to their `favorite_fruits` column stored in the table `users`. When adding an item to `favorite_fruits`, we want to add the `fruit_id` of the item in `fruits` rather than the name and keep them comma delimited. When we query a list of users in the application, we want to receive a single row for each user and display their `favorite_fruits` as name. To get halfway there I need a left join on the `fruits` table and cross apply string_split on the `favorite_fruits` column to receive the text/name values. At this point I will receive a row for each fruit listed in the `favorite_fruits`. To get the last half I need to then merge rows with common `user_id`. See below for the desired result.

`users` table

| user_id | favorite_fruits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3,6 |
| 2 | 2,5 |

`fruits` table

| fruit_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | banana |
| 2 | strawberry |
| 3 | blueberry |
| 4 | papaya |
| 5 | orange |
| 6 | apple |

Desired results

| user_id | favorite_fruits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blueberry,apple |
| 2 | strawberry,orange |

I understand that using comma delimited values will break normalization and go against 1NF. I would like to see if this example is feasible and why.

Comment: The obvious answer would be "no". Use a normalised design. Then you can implement proper referential integrity. Instead, here you'd need to split your data, `JOIN` it, and then reaggregate the strings, and you have no way of using things like `FOREIGN KEY`s to ensure someone doesn't insert a value of `99,654` for the user's favourite fruits.

Comment: Create a favorite fruits _table_, not a column, then you can have a proper one-to-many relationship instead of this hack of comma-separated values.

Comment: And if you know how things must be done, why you feel the urge to do it wrong? Use a normalized design from start, when you grow your sistem and have 1'7 million users, you would regret the 'it's only a couple miliseconds slower', ....

Comment: @AaronBertrand Would that mean I need a separate table for every multi-select field on that exists on a form in my application?

Comment: @Larnu I found this where someone has the same kind of question. Is this also incorrect and should be avoided? - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-structure-data-table-fields-when-using-multiple-select-drop-down

Comment: Yes, @mojojojo8 , that is the principle behind a many to many relationship. You end up with 3 tables per relationship; in this case a `User` and `Fruit` and and `FavouriteFruits` table. If you then asked the User for their favourite Colour(s) you would also have a `Colour` and a `FavouriteColours` table.

Comment: String split, join, string agg. But order of ID list may or may not match the resulting name list.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence is important, you can use JSON to split the string where [key] will be the proper order.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d74853b8836a5b9aa392637d6c1b989)**

```
Select A.user_id
      ,B.*
 From users A
 Cross Apply (
                Select favorite_fruits=string_agg(B2.[Name],',') within group (order by [key])
                 From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape([favorite_fruits],'json'),',','","')+'"]' ) B1
                 Join fruits B2 on B2.[fruit_id] = B1.Value
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
user_id favorite_fruits
1       blueberry,apple
2       strawberry,orange
```

**Note:**

If `[favorite_fruits]` is truly a string of numbers, the `OpenJSON` portion can look like this

```
From  OpenJSON( '['+[favorite_fruits]+']' )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not store denormalized data.** Normalize your database, and store each value as a separate row in a many:many join table.

So you need a new `user_favoriteFruit` table (note how the primary key is a composite key)

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_favoriteFruit (
    user_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES users (user_id),
    fruit_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES fruits (fruit_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, fruit_id)
);

INSERT user_favoriteFruit (user_id, fruit_id) VALUES
(1, 3),
(1, 6),
(2, 2),
(2, 5);
```

You can then get your expected results using aggregation, like this

```sql
SELECT
  uf.user_id,
  favorite_fruits = STRING_AGG(f.name, ',')
FROM user_favoriteFruit uf
JOIN fruits f ON f.fruit_id = uf.fruit_id;
GROUP BY
  uf.user_id;
```

If ordering is important then add another `ordering` column to the join table.